# Best way to prepare values of varying types for combined hashing in C#?

Tags: c#, hash, .net-core

I have a few values of varying types which I need to combine together before hashing to create a value that is unique to this combination. Security isn't particularly important, just that the values are guaranteed unique.

Is this a safe approach, and furthermore are there any issues with this approach that I should know about?

```
public string GetHash(int x, int y, DateTime z, string w)
        {
            string concat = x.ToString() + y.ToString() + z.Ticks.ToString() + w;
            byte[] hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(concat));
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hash);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the difference between `x=11, y=2` and `x=1, y=12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not necessarily reliable, because the system that verifies the hash could have different culture settings. You could address this by adding `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to your `ToString()` calls.

```
using System.Globalization
...
string concat = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              + y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              + z.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
              + w;
```

You may also be subject to collisions, since your fields align ambiguously (e.g. "11" + "2" is the same as "1" + "12"). You can address that by adding delimiters or using a fixed width format.

```
string concat = x.ToString("0000000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              + y.ToString("0000000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
              + z.Ticks.ToString("0000000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
              + w;
```

Or

```
string concat = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              + "|"
              + y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              + "|"
              + z.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
              + "|"
              + w;
```